# Recoil state management how can I persist data using recoil-persist and how can I dynamically change effects_UNSTABLE localStorage or sessionStorage

Tags: reactjs, persist

[image]
I am trying to change the recoil-persist local storage to session storage dynamically, but it only first time call when update store type effects_UNSTABLE not update .